# Issue with flutter_intl while using same key in parent and child package?

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-intl

So we are using a key let say `paidTo` in the parent app and then we developed another child package which is having same key in intl.arb but it has placeholder as well,

Sample String from `.arb` file of the PARENT APP,

```
"paidTo": "Paid to ",
```

Sample string from `.arb` file of the CHILD PACKAGE,

```
"paidTo" : "Paid to {payeeName}",
  "@paidTo" : {
    "placeholders": {
      "payeeName" : {
        "type" : "String",
        "example" : "John"
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the exact error,

```
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'MessageLookupByLibrary.simpleMessage.<anonymous closure>'
Receiver: Closure: () => String
Tried calling: MessageLookupByLibrary.simpleMessage.<anonymous closure>("payeeName")
Found: MessageLookupByLibrary.simpleMessage.<anonymous closure>() => String
```

and stack trace of this is:

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      _objectNoSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:85:9)
#2      Function._apply (dart:core-patch/function_patch.dart:11:73)
#3      Function.apply (dart:core-patch/function_patch.dart:34:12)
#4      MessageLookupByLibrary.evaluateMessage (package:intl/message_lookup_by_library.dart:123:21)
#5      MessageLookupByLibrary.lookupMessage (package:intl/message_lookup_by_library.dart:117:14)
#6      CompositeMessageLookup.lookupMessage (package:intl/message_lookup_by_library.dart:53:21)
#7      Intl._lookupMessage (package:intl/intl.dart:180:10)
#8      Intl._message (package:intl/intl.dart:174:12)
#9      Intl.message (package:intl/intl.dart:168:7)
```

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm (Rosetta), locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
```